# Concatenate multiple results from an index match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, string-concatenation, textjoin

I'm trying to concat multiple results from an index match into one cell. Here is an example data set I'm working with:

[image]

My desired results:

[image]

As you can see, I'm trying to find all customers where the data is 4/12/2017. I then want to combine them into one string in another cell. I've figured out how to sum up the quantity if the date is the same, but just can't figure out how to concatenate the customer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the newer TEXTJOIN function as an array formula with CSE.

```
=textjoin("|", true, if(a2:a10=date(2017, 4, 12), c2:c10, text(,)))
```

If your Excel version does not support TEXTJOIN, search this site for [excel][textjoin] for alternatives. Example: [TEXTJOIN for xl2010/xl2013 with criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2010-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050?s=1|85.2925#50719050)

[image]

Comment: Alternatives need some VBA IIRC, do you confirm it?

Comment: @A.S.H - Yes, or a finite limit of possible outcomes.