# Vlookup return multiple values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup, textjoin

I am trying to do Vlookup to return multiple values. However, the function takes really long to load. Is there any way to make it faster ? I got the function from online: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2706-excel-vlookup-return-multiple-values-in-one-cell.html

```
  Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim xResult As String
  xResult = ""
  For Each rng In pWorkRng
   If rng = pValue Then
    xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
  End If
 Next
 MYVLOOKUP = xResult
 End Function
```

This is the code in the sub

```
 Sub sort()
Dim x As Integer
Dim result As Variant
Dim name As String
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  x = 10
 Do Until IsEmpty(Sheet9.Cells(x, 1).Value)
 name = Sheet9.Cells(x, 1).Value
 result = MYVLOOKUP(name, Sheet9.Range("K:M"), 3)
 Sheet9.Cells(x, 4).Value = result
 x = x + 1
 Loop
 End Sub
```

Comment: When you get '*the function from online*', it is considered good manners to accredit the original author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Sheet9.Range("K:M")` passed into the UDF as the *pWorkRng* parameter, it is used in the `For Each rng In pWorkRng` loop. This means that you are going to examine three entire columns or 3,145,728 cells; most of which are completely empty and two columns of which are not necessary for a VLOOKUP in any event. Small wonder why things are running slow.

Either cut the range(s) down to the active area of data or use Intersect to trim full column references down to the .UsedRange.

```
Option Explicit

Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xResult As String

    xResult = vbnullstring
    'the next line trims pWorkRng down to the .UsedRange
    Set pWorkRng = Intersect(pWorkRng, pWorkRng.Parent.UsedRange)

    'if you only want to examione the first column then use the following
    'For Each rng In pWorkRng.columns(1)
    'if you want to look through K, L and M for pValues then use this one,
    For Each rng In pWorkRng
        If rng = pValue Then
            xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
       End If
    Next
    MYVLOOKUP = trim(xResult)
 End Function
```

I've added an option to only look in the first column. Your comparison is also case-sensitive; you might actually want that but VLOOKUP is typically **not** case-sensitive.

Comment: You can also do this with [tag:textjoin]. See [Concatenate multiple results from an index match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352819/concatenate-multiple-results-from-an-index-match).

Comment: How to i add comma after the results. I add it in this line: xResult = xResult & " , " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1). However it show out as " , a , b , c"

Comment: It sounds like to want to end in a comma. If that is the case then reverse the string concatenation order with `xResult = xResult & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1) & ", "`